# This RegEx Works Only For 8 Digits Phone Number, How To Make It Works For 15 Digits?

Tags: php, regex

Someone in Stack Overflow gave me this code:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/(\+?\d{2}|0)(\d{7,8})/', '0$2', $test);
```

It changes user input:

> +622112345 into 02112345
>
> 622112345 into 02112345
>
> 02112345 into 02112345

Unfortunately it only works for 7-8 digits. I decided to change the code into this:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/(\+?\d{2}|0)(\d{15})/', '0$2', $test);
```

By changing `(\d{7,8})` into `(\d{15})`, I hoped I could get this RegEx to validate up to 15 digits. But, here's what I have:

```
input : 083812345678910 >> output : 083812345678910 [correct]

input : 6283812345678910 >> output : 6283812345678910 [false, should be : 083812345678910]

input : +6283812345678910 >> output : 6283812345678910 [false, should be : 083812345678910]
```

How can I make this works on 15 digit numbers? Thanks.

UPDATE : user input can be 10, 11, 12 or even 13 digits. but not more than 15 digits. so I need this code to change the prefix : either +62, 62 or 0 INTO 0xxxx. no matter how many digits they have, 15 maximum.

Comment: Wait, do you need it to be valid up to 15 digits or exactly 15 digits?  {15} means exactly 15.  {7,15} would mean between 7 and 15 digits (inclusive).

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: @BlackVegetable : check my update. I added some new information on my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct regex is:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/(0|\+?\d{2})(\d{7,14})/', '0$2', $test);
```

Even though you have 16 digit numbers, there should only be at most 14 digits after the extension, to account for the 2 digit extension. Note that this will work for more extensions other than `62`, if this is not desired, replace `\d{2}` with `62`.

[Demo](http://viper-7.com/GFI3D9)

Comment: having `(\d{7,14})` gives me false result : input : 083812345678910, output : 03812345678910 (missing 8, should be 083812345678910)

Comment: @RobertHanson - I updated my answer. As you can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/GFI3D9) now all of the test cases are correctly replaced.